# middleware auth with multiple pages Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm try to have login, register, recovery pages protected, currently I have login page protected on middleware like so

```js
export default function({ app, route, redirect }) {
  if (route.path !== "/account/login") {
    //we are on a protected route
    if (!app.$fire.auth.currentUser) {
      //take them to sign in page
      return redirect("/account/login");
    }
  } else if (route.path === "/account/login") {
    if (!app.$fire.auth.currentUser) {
      //leave them on the sign in page
    } else {
      return redirect("/");
    }
  }
}
```

but I can't access register or recovery via nuxt-link, can I use middleware to protect those pages and render.

Comment: it seems we want these pages to be publicly available without being authenticated: login, register, and recovery page. Is that correct? If yes then the logic seen here needs to be adjusted.

Comment: `I can't access register or recovery via nuxt-link`, what does this one mean? Also, you could probably make a conditional on several paths, to check if they need an authentication and let the user pass or not.

Comment: hey Kunukn yes Im trying that, I have only the login set up with that function